# Finding CORS-friendly images online

Tags: javascript, image, cross-domain, webgl, cors

WebGL only allows to use images as textures for which the hosting webserver explicitly [allows to use cross-origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Are there image databases that I can use with my WebGL?

Comment: Why don't you simply download those images to store them with your html files ? Or set a proxy on your server ?

Comment: @dystroy - Aren't both of these approaches bandwidth-burners? (the 2nd more so than the 1st, of course)

Comment: Not so much, especially for static cachable files. And letting the burden on the original server doesn't seem really correct.

Comment: @dystroy: I'm interested in picking **lots** of random pictures off the web for some sort of stress testing with WebGL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google Picasa, which supports CORS-requests (Source: [WebGL Up and Running](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/144932357X) page 163).